# How to integrate gspread with aiohttp

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp, gspread

I am trying to use gspread, but I need the library to mesh well with another async library I am using.

After digging through the docs for gspread, I found this function that I can use:

```
class gspread.Client(auth, session=None)
An instance of this class communicates with Google API.

Parameters: 
auth – An OAuth2 credential object. Credential objects are those created by the oauth2client library. https://github.com/google/oauth2client
session – (optional) A session object capable of making HTTP requests while persisting some parameters across requests. Defaults to requests.Session.
```

Which gives me an optional `session` parameter. How would I specify the session to use aiohttp?

I wrote a bit of test code, which compiles fine, but running the code crashes.

```
import aiohttp
import gspread
import random
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
c = gspread.authorize(creds)
client = gspread.Client(auth=c, session=aiohttp.ClientSession)
sheet = client.open_by_key('1Hkwo9gSpk3NjgPLPkG8kh0zBNw2nxsYWRw0cVdn0JA0')

ws = sheet.get_worksheet(0)
rcount = ws.row_count
msg = ws.cell(random.randint(1,rcount),1).value
print(msg)
```

The error message I get is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\xxxxx\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 118, in <module>
    vspd.debug(filename, port_num, '', '', run_as)
  File "c:\Users\xxxxx\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\debugger.py", line 37, in debug
    run(address, filename, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\xxxxx\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_local.py", line 79, in run_file
    run(argv, addr, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\xxxxx\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_local.py", line 140, in _run
    _pydevd.main()
  File "c:\Users\xxxxx\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1751, in main
    debugger.connect(host, port)
  File "c:\Users\xxxxx\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1107, in run
    return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
  File "c:\Users\xxxxx\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1114, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "c:\Users\xxxxx\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 25, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "c:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Coding\Discord Bot\Testing\test.py", line 14, in <module>
    ws = sheet.get_worksheet(0)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\gspread\models.py", line 141, in get_worksheet
    sheet_data = self.fetch_sheet_metadata()
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\gspread\models.py", line 123, in fetch_sheet_metadata
    r = self.client.request('get', url, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 73, in request
    headers=headers
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
PS C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Coding\Discord Bot>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52899351/edit) your question to include the specific error(s) you are getting. Odds are you can’t pass in any arbitrary thing called session. It probably needs to conform to the same API as the default one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, once I posted this question, I found that someone made an async wrapper for gspread. Check out the library [here](https://pypi.org/project/gspread-asyncio/) and show this guy your appreciation. I sure am!

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to use `aiohttp` with current version of `gspread` (3.0.1). the `gspread` library uses synchronous calls and `aiohttp` uses asynchronous calls.

Please, reconsider to use compatible library like `requests` or `httplib2`.

Comment: Isn't that what the function I posted in the main question would achieve? If I make the session use aiohttp that would achieve my end goal, no? I'm talking about this specific definition: 

https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.Client



Would it be possible, instead, to control threading with gspread?

Comment: to create a session you don't need an *async* call, but to call a get method from it, you need to `await` it. gspread does all call synchronously. Otherwise, you'll have async interface for many methods.

Comment: By default `gspread` uses a new `requests.Session` for itself, but you may provide a session you have one beforehand.

Comment: `gspread` by iteslf doesn't directly produce any additional threads.